# Button for Grid View of Images

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, gridview, uiimage

I have a `grid view of images`...how can I make changes in my code to make it clickable for every image.

How can I recive a click event for each image?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


int Columns = 3;
int Rows=5;

int space = 10;
int width = (self.view.frame.size.width-(Columns)*space)/Columns;
int height = width;
int x = space;
int y = space;  
UIScrollView *Scroll=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y,self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) ];
[Scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(Columns*(space+width)+space, Rows*(space+(self.view.frame.size.height-(Columns)*space)/Columns)+space)];
Scroll.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
Scroll.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;

for(int i=1 ;i<30;i++)
{
    j++;


    NSLog(@"j= %i",j);


    label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];

    image= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)];
    image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%02ds.jpg", i+1]]; 



    [Scroll addSubview:label];

    if (i%Columns == 0) {
        y += space+height;
        x = space;
    } else {
        x+=space+width;
    }
    [Scroll addSubview:image];

}
[self.view addSubview:Scroll];


}
```

Comment: Please use whitespace and indentation to make your code redable.

Comment: ok..how can i make images clickable...

Comment: Please try to use standard naming and coding conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for your purpose.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
imageView.tag=TAG; //Tag your imageview to identify in call back
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
[tapRecognizer release];    //If not ARC
```

Write action callback as follows...

```
-(void)imageTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    if ([tapRecognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
        if (tapRecognizer.view.tag==TAG) { //Identify image view tag
            //Your code for image tap action
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya but..I can give tag for only for one image ryt...beacuse it will be in for loop below to label...`imageView.tag=TAG` ...then for every row...same event will be perform ryt...

Comment: For example you can use the value of loop variable `i` as tag, so `imageView.tag=i` tells you the position of imageView in your grid

Comment: no i didn't get u....how to use this and where UITapGestureRecognizer in my code...so that suppose i create 10 image views...then how to give 10 tags...

Comment: you can write code to `addGestureRecognizer` above your `[Scroll addSubview:label];` line

Answer (score 3):

It is possible using UIImage as well but I prefer UIButton in case it need to be tappable. Since UIImageView directly inherits from UIView it doesn't really know targets and selectors.

```
UIButton *imageButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];   
imageButton.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height
[imageButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:
                   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%02ds.jpg", i+1]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

  [imageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(imageButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];



    -(void)imageButtonTapped:(id) sender
    {
      //Do whatever you want to do on image tap.      
    }
```

Comment: I agree this seems the the simplest and cleanest option

Comment: but it will create single event for every button..ryt...i want if 10 button is there every one has separate click event

Comment: Create 10 buttons with 10 separate implementations then

Comment: no not 10 implementations... you get (id)sender as parameter and you can identify which button is tapped with this param. One way to identify buttons/views is use of tags as I've shown in my answer.

Comment: You have asked "if 10 button is there every one has separate click event" which sounds like you want a separate event for each button? By using UI button you can detect a touch event, implement that event/s how you wish

Comment: @Atif can you tell me ...how to give `get (id)sender as parameter and you can identify which button is tapped with this param`

Comment: This param is passed automatically and it's the button which gets tapped.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating your own GridView, I suggest using GMGridView
http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/gmgridview

It is a great control that handles all of the clicks and everything already-- you just need to implement the delegate methods and follow the examples. I have used it before with great results; the delegate/data source methods are very similar to a UITableView so it is not too confusing at first.

If you don't want to include an external class then I would suggest doing what [MSK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13995679/480415) said--